# Debugging Static Constructor in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm, .net-5

I'm running into a situation where I'd like to debug a static constructor in a WPF project but it appears to be executed before I can attach the debugger. This involves debugging a viewmodel whose configuration depends upon, among other things, whether or not I'm designing a WPF UI element (i.e., viewing a WPF window in the VS designer) or running the app.

This is part of a Net5 (Net Core) WPF app which uses the prerelease Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm package.

Here's the relevant viewmodel constructor code:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    private readonly IJ4JLogger _logger;
    private readonly DesktopImagerDataLayer _dataLayer;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if( !AppConfiguration.InDesignMode )
            _dataLayer = AppConfiguration.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DesktopImagerDataLayer>();

        _logger = AppConfiguration.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IJ4JLogger>();
        _logger.SetLoggedType( this.GetType() );

    }
}
```

`AppConfiguration` holds certain (static) properties that I want to use throughout the app (e.g., an `IServiceProvider` instance). Here's its definition:

```
public class AppConfiguration
{
    static AppConfiguration()
    {
        var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;

        InDesignMode = (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(prop, typeof(System.Windows.FrameworkElement))
            .Metadata.DefaultValue;

        var builder = new AppServicesBuilder(
            "c:/Programming/DesktopImager/DesktopImagerManager/design-time-settings");

        if (!InDesignMode)
            builder.AddModule(new DesktopImagerDbAutofacModule());

        ServiceProvider = builder.Build();

        ScaledFolder = builder.ScaledFolder;
        ThumbnailFolder = builder.ThumbnailFolder;
    }

    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }
    public static string ScaledFolder { get; }
    public static string ThumbnailFolder { get; }
    public static bool InDesignMode { get; }
}
```

Because the viewmodel is referenced in an XAML window definition the static constructor apparently gets called as soon as the WpfSurface process fires up...which is fine, except that since the only way I know to debug design-time problems is to attach another instance of VS to the WpfSurface process I've got a chicken and egg problem :).

The only workaround I've found is to make AppConfiguration provide those properties as instance properties and create an instance of AppConfiguration when I need to access them (e.g., in the viewmodel constructor). That allows me to attach to WpfSurface and debug how AppConfiguration works...but it's not terribly convenient. Plus, it seems like recreating IServiceProvider every time I need to use it isn't a good practice so it's not something I'd want in a released product.

Is there another way to debug static constructors at design time in a WPF project? Is there a different way of creating app-wide single-instance properties (e.g., IServiceProvider) that I should be using in a WPF project which would eliminate the need for a static constructor?

Comment: Instead of attaching the debugger to a running process, can't you just start the program in the debugger. Alternatively, you yould add a [Debugger.Launch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=net-5.0) statement (works on Windows only)

Comment: Thanx, @KlausGütter. At design time the app isn’t running but the WpfSurface process still evaluates parts of the codebase in order to display a “live” view of the window. But I’ll give the Debugger.Launch() idea a try as I’d forgotten that.

Comment: "Is there a different way of creating app-wide single-instance properties (e.g., IServiceProvider) that I should be using in a WPF project which would eliminate the need for a static constructor?" - dependency-injection containers